# Background sizing on mobile

Tags: html, css, background

So what I am trying to do is reproduce this effect (which can be seen using chrome Version 45.0.2454.101 m). The important thing to notice is that each div is displaying a piece of the overall background image in the wrapper (except it is actually a separate image of the same size that is modified by inverting the colors so you can see the difference).

Basically it appears as though each content div is using a background image that is the size of the document itself.

Structure:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
        Here is some content
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        Here is some more content
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        So much content
    </div>
</div>
```

However, if you were to go visit this link on your mobile device you'll notice that now each div is using its own background image and not overlaying with the wrapper's background image. The background image is now the same size of the content div and is positioned per content div. Why is this happening and how can I get the mobile website to look like the one experienced in a desktop browser? (I am also using chrome on mobile)

[Link to JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bL0s5ch2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos for the effort, but this is simply not going to work as it depends on `background-attachment:fixed`. Mobile browsers try to actively improve the view experience by 'intelligently' handling certain page content differently, especially when it seems desktop-optimized.

One of the things they choose to do is ignore things like `background-attachment:fixed`, because usually it breaks more than it enhances on not-so-intelligently designed pages on a miniature screen.

So I'm sorry but http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-attachment is your problem here, and it's not going away soon  :)